# Select multiple rows depending on value of A1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with employees and data listed. The drop-down in A1 lets someone select the employee and then it hides the rows for all other employees. I want to add the names of supervisors in the drop-down of A1 and have it select only the employees under that supervisor and hide the rest. The number of employees under each supervisor ranges from 3 to 6.
This is what I have to hide the rows when selecting a single employee : 
The data is on worksheet1 and the list of employees and supervisors is on sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v As Variant, i, j As Long
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

    UsedRange.Rows.Hidden = False
    If IsEmpty(Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    v = Cells(1, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To 40 ' Show/Hide the Analysts rows - Add/Substract to the second number when adding/removing analysts
        If Not Cells(i, 1) = v Then Rows(i).Hidden = True
        If v = "Select Analysts/Supervisors" Then Rows(i).Hidden = False
    Next i


    Cells(2, 1).Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Cells(2, 1).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this? I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: look at the Range.Autofilter method.

Comment: An idea: You could use DataValidation on 2 cells. Say A1 is DataValidation on list "Supervisors", and say A2 on list "Analysts". Change in Sheet2 such that a column of Supervisors (name the column "Supervisors") and then on a blank column, name it "Analysts". Use `Worksheet_Change` on Sheet1!A1 to clear and copy values of those employees under the selected supervisor into the "Analysts". This then updates the list in Sheet1!A2.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i did right understand your question and excel workbook stucture.

You have to create range on the data sheet (in this example its named range: 'rngSupervisors')
In this range you put your supervisors names (column headers)
under each supervisor you write the employees. Each row, 1 employee.

The supervisors itself must be in your employee list to select it, for drop down.

so the data worksheet has for eaxample:

B1: supervisor1
C1: supervisor2
D1: supervisor3

than the employees
B2: emplyee1_UnderSupervisor1
B2: emplyee2_UnderSupervisor1
B2: emplyee3_UnderSupervisor1

C2: emplyee1_UnderSupervisor2
C2: emplyee2_UnderSupervisor2
.
.

then you have to name this range "B1:D1" as "rngSupervisors"

In this example the data worksheet is the second one. I would advise you to use the named worksheet, or better direct reference it (give name of worksheet in VBA editor, than you can reference it directly).

Here i created the a function that tests if Argument1-string is the advisor of Argument2-string. Than you can use this function to test it, if it is false, and the name dont match, than you can hide the row.

I tried to make minimal modifications on your code (but it could be good improved.. or the method you make it all, could be probably realised with excel filters)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v As Variant, i, j As Long
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

    UsedRange.Rows.Hidden = False
    If IsEmpty(Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    v = Cells(1, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To 40 ' Show/Hide the Analysts rows - Add/Substract to the second number when adding/removing analysts
        'if the name is not under selected supervisor, and its not selected name, hide the row
        If Not isSupervisor(CStr(v), CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)) And Not Cells(i, 1) = v Then
            Rows(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i


    Cells(2, 1).Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Cells(2, 1).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'returns true if sEmplName is under sSupName supervisor
Private Function isSupervisor(sSupName As String, sEmplName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wksDataSheet As Worksheet 'worksheet where supervisor and employes data saved
    Dim rngSupCell As Range 'range with supervisor names/headers
    Dim lSupColumn As Long 'column of selected supervisor
    Dim lSupLastRow As Long 'last row with employes names of column of supervisor
    Dim lCurrentRow As Long 'counter for current row by iteration

    Set wksDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2) 'or some named sheet for example ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet")

    With wksDataSheet
        'for each cell in supervisor names range
        For Each rngSupCell In .Range("rngSupervisors") 'could be .Range("A3:A6") for example
            'if supervisor name found in the range
            If StrComp(rngSupCell.Value, sSupName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                'get column
                lSupColumn = rngSupCell.Column
                'get last row
                lSupLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
                'for each employee name, starts from next row
                For lCurrentRow = rngSupCell.row + 1 To lSupLastRow
                    'if equals, return true, exit.
                    If StrComp(.Cells(lCurrentRow, lSupColumn).Value, sEmplName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        isSupervisor = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next lCurrentRow
            End If
        Next rngSupCell
    End With

    'nothing found, return false
    isSupervisor = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried modifying this to work but it didn't. My workbook has stats data on the "Master" sheet(sheet #1) and analysts and supervisors on "Analysts" sheet(sheet #12). Data validation for cell A1 on "Master" sheet has all the analysts and supervisors in the first column of "Analysts" sheet with title "Select Analyst" in cell A1. I modified the "Analysts" sheet to show supervisors from B1:I1 and listed the analysts in the columns then  created a named range for the rngSupervisors. When I try to change the data validation on "Master sheet" it says I cannot reference a range.

Comment: looks right, the `Set wksDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)` should be `Set wksDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysts")` or `Set wksDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(12)` in your case. Make sure it is so.
Then check if your named range really exists, and has the name "rngSupervisors" on Analysts sheet.

Here is example you can download:
[drop-vba.xlsm](http://sro-account.de/filez/stackoverflow/dropdown-vba.xlsm)